# I cant write to a file

Tags: python

I run the program and key.txt still stays empty

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

keys = []

def on_press(key):
    global keys
    keys.append(key)
    print("{0} pressed".format(key))
    write_file(keys)
    keys = []

def write_file(keys):
    with open("key.txt", "a") as f:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'", "")
            if k.find("space") >= 0:
                f.write('\n')
            elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                f.write(k)


def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Is it just writing `\n` so the file *looks* empty?

Comment: I've tried this out, and the `on_press` and `on_release` functions seem only to be called for certain keys, such as shift and control. I'm not familiar with pynput, so I don't know if that is intended or a bug with the library.

Comment: By the way, when someone (or several people) edit your question to fix the formatting, please don't reedit your question to mess it up again.